# Wordpress query update not updating all posts

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, metadata

I have a code to change a meta value periodically with cronjob. This cod is outside of wordpress. It updates only first 8 products.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_key' => '_sale_price',
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

while($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();

    update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "_regular_price", '$new_value');

endwhile;
```

How can I change all the post meta values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your WordPress install configured to show eight posts per page, perchance? You probably want to add `'posts_per_page'=>-1` to your argument array, so that the Loop will go through them all...

(I'm assuming your `$new_value` was just an example placeholder, and that you know it won't be interpolated between single quotes, as other people have mentioned...)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It has worked very well. As you told, it was just an example for placeholding. But I saw that I need more queries when I dig the project. Can I change this value by "$data * _regular_price" where _sale_price = 10 only?

Answer (score 1):

In your code `update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "_regular_price", '$new_value');`

`$new_value` is inside single quotes, php wont treat it as variable. It should be in double quotes so that php translates that variable and then your update function should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
while($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();

    update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "_regular_price", "$new_value");

endwhile;
```

> You need to **Double Quote** `$new_value`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'product',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page'   => -1,
      'meta_key' => '_sale_price',
    );
```

posts_per_page => -1 stands for all posts.

Answer (score -1):

you can try to change $args with

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',      
);
```

P.S I have not tested this;